# IndexError: string index out of range ... why in this small piece of code?

Tags: string, python-3.x, indexoutofboundsexception

```
s='saamaarrr'
for i in range(0, len(s)-1):
    while(s[i]==s[i+1]):
        i+=1
        print(s[i])
```

IndexError: string index out of range

I am new to python. I know the reasons for this error. But i don't know why it is occurring here. i've read other answers to this question also

Comment: you are calling `s[i+1]` inside of a for loop that goes until `len(s) -1)`. When `i = len(s) -1`, `i+1` will be out of range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Range objects include the left bound and exclude the right bound
If the string is 9 characters long, as it is in your case, the range sequence would be:
 `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`

Let's take a look at what happens when the variable `i` in the `for` loop reaches 8.
 In your `while` loop, you're checking if `s[8]` is equal to `s[9]`. Since indexing in Python starts from 0, as in many other programming languages, the last letter of your string `s` would have an index 8, which means that index 9 is out of range of the string. This causes an error.

To fix it, make your `for` loop like this:

```
for i in range(0, len(s)-2):
```

This way the range sequence will be `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7`, so it won't cause an error.

Also, you don't have to specify the left bound as 0, it is a default value, so this also works:

```
for i in range(len(s)-2):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(s[i] == s[i+1])
```

That's causing problems because when i = len(s)-1, s[i+1] will be out of range!

You don't need nest a while loop inside of your for loop.  Adjust the range statement in your FOR and try an if statement instead...

```
for i in range(0, len(s)-2):
    If s[i]==s[i+1]:
        print(s[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you want to access the value of `s[i+1]` before testing the actual value of `i+1`. I also suggest that you don't use the same variable (i) in both your `for` and `while` loops.

Here is the result :

```
s='saamaarrr'
for i in range(0, len(s)-1):
    j = i + 1
    while (j < len(s)) and (s[i]==s[j]):
        print(s[j])
        j+=1
```

And here is the output :

```
a
a
r
r
r
```

Don't know what you want to achieve, though...

Hope it'll be helpful !